# Getting the lower level XML object to insert an image into a chart in Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi

In an older question I asked this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60084790/is-there-a-way-i-can-add-a-picture-inside-a-chart?noredirect=1#comment106280532_60084790

But was told it was too complicated to answer.

I would like to try, but I am not sure where to start. How would I get the XML object? Would using the Dom Node be helpful at all?

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to start for such tasks:

At first do what you need using Excel's GUI. In this case create a chart in Excel and put a shape into chart space of that chart. Save it as `*.xlsx`.

Now unzip that `*.xlsx` using a ZIP-tool. You will see the internally directory structure containing multiple XML files.

Now determine what needs to be done to achieve your goal.

In this case have a look at `/xl/charts/chart1.xml`. Try to get how the shape is described there. You will find:

```
<c:chartSpace ... >
 ...
 <c:userShapes r:id="rId1"/>
</c:chartSpace>
```

So the shape is a reference to an `rId1`. This refers to `/xl/charts/_rels/chart1.xml.rels`. And this contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
 <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/chartUserShapes" Target="../drawings/drawing2.xml"/>
</Relationships>
```

So it refers to `../drawings/drawing2.xml` which is `/xl/drawings/drawing2.xml` in the `*.xlsx` ZIP archive. And this contains XML which describes the shape but is of type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chartshapes+xml` while default drawings are `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawing+xml`.

Now you know what needs to be done to put a shape into a chart's  chart space.

1. Create the `/xl/drawings/drawing2.xml` in the `*.xlsx` ZIP-archive which describes the shape. `Apache poi` does not provide this. It only provides `XSSFDrawing`. But it provides `POIXMLDocumentPart` which needs to be extended to describe a `XSSFChartShapesDrawing`. One could have a look at source `XSSFDrawing.java` to get a clue of what needs to be there.
2. Create the `/xl/charts/_rels/chart1.xml.rels`. `XSSFChart` (`XDDFChart`)  also extends `POIXMLDocumentPart`. So it provides `POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart addRelation(java.lang.String relId, POIXMLRelation relationshipType, POIXMLDocumentPart part)`. But of course there is no predefined `POIXMLRelation` for a chart user shape drawing. So this also would must be described using code.
3. Put `<c:userShapes r:id="rId1"/>` into the chart's XML. This is the simplest task. `XDDFChart` provides `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTChart getCTChart()` and `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTChartSpace getCTChartSpace()` to get the underlying low level objects.
4. Don't forget to note the new content type in `/[Content_Types].xml` of the `*.xlsx` ZIP-archive. Would must be `<Override ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chartshapes+xml" PartName="/xl/drawings/drawing2.xml"/>`.